# How to find out if I'm using Bluetooth 3.0 + HS

Tags: bluetooth

I recently bought a Hama bluetooth 3.0+HS dongle. I'm using it with my Ubuntu 10.04. Ubuntu recognizes the dongle and I am able to set up BT devices. But how can I check whether it is actually using version 3.0 rather than 2.1?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to check bluetooth version on my laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/591803/how-to-check-bluetooth-version-on-my-laptop)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Run the `hciconfig -a` command, it'll list all Bluetooth devices and the supported versions

```
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
        BD Address: 00:1C:7B:A5:91:F2  ACL MTU: 310:10  SCO MTU: 64:8
        UP RUNNING PSCAN 
        RX bytes:1090 acl:0 sco:0 events:38 errors:0
        TX bytes:1381 acl:0 sco:0 commands:37 errors:0
        Features: 0xff 0xff 0x8f 0xfe 0x9b 0xff 0x59 0x83
        Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
        Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF PARK 
        Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
        Name: 'machine-0'
        Class: 0x5a0100
        Service Classes: Networking, Capturing, Object Transfer, Telephony
        Device Class: Computer, Uncategorized
        HCI Version: 2.1 (0x4)  Revision: 0x12e7
        LMP Version: 2.1 (0x4)  Subversion: 0x12e7
        Manufacturer: Cambridge Silicon Radio (10)
```

As you can see, my device only supports 2.1 (HCI Version).

Comment: Alright. Can I somehow also check for the HS channel capabilities?

Comment: I don't know, try searching in the manual pages or the ubuntu help pages.