# how to check bluetooth version on my laptop

Tags: bluetooth

I bought new laptop Lenovo Z50-70 and have installed Ubuntu 14.04. I want to check whether the Bluetooth shipped is v4 or v3?

I know I should check it from main website or from BIOS, but I am curious to find it from command line. Any help please

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/114560/how-to-find-out-if-im-using-bluetooth-3-0-hs

Answer (score 80, accepted):

That info can be found with `hciconfig -a`:

```
$ hciconfig -a
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 5C:93:A2:A3:59:56  ACL MTU: 1022:8  SCO MTU: 183:5
    […]
    HCI Version:  (0x7)  Revision: 0x3101
    LMP Version:  (0x7)  Subversion: 0x1
    Manufacturer: Atheros Communications, Inc. (69)
```

In recent years, `hciconfig` [has been deprecated](https://github.com/chrippa/ds4drv/issues/123), and [mostly replaced](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/bluetooth#Deprecated_BlueZ_tools) by `btmgmt` and `bluetoothctl`.

```
$ btmgmt info
Index list with 1 item
hci0:   Primary controller
        addr 5C:93:A2:A3:59:56 version 7 manufacturer 69 class 0x6c0100
        […]
```

There is a table mapping each numbered version to each Bluetooth specification version:

```
| hex | dec |Bluetooth|
|-----|-----|---------|
| 0x0 |   0 | 1.0b    |
| 0x1 |   1 | 1.1     |
| 0x2 |   2 | 1.2     |
| 0x3 |   3 | 2.0+EDR |
| 0x4 |   4 | 2.1+EDR |
| 0x5 |   5 | 3.0+HS  |
| 0x6 |   6 | 4.0     |
| 0x7 |   7 | 4.1     |
| 0x8 |   8 | 4.2     |
| 0x9 |   9 | 5.0     |
| 0xa |  10 | 5.1     |
| 0xb |  11 | 5.2     |
| 0xc |  12 | 5.3     |
| 0xd |  13 | 5.4     |
```

This mapping is defined at section *2.1 Core specification versions* from [Assigned Numbers Document (PDF)](https://btprodspecificationrefs.blob.core.windows.net/assigned-numbers/Assigned%20Number%20Types/Assigned_Numbers.pdf), and [also available as YAML](https://bitbucket.org/bluetooth-SIG/public/src/main/assigned_numbers/core/core_version.yaml). Both can be found from [Bluetooth Specifications](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/) → [Assigned Numbers](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/) page.

If you're interested, there is also a table for the assigned manufacturer numbers, among many other tables.

Comment: the [output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10501268/) is here, i cant find version

Comment: Turn the bluetooth on and try the command again.  I think my bluetooth has the same ID and I could check it later

Comment: new output [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10502013/)

Comment: Looks like `(0x7)` means it is 4.1 `HCI Version: 4.1 (0x7)  Revision: 0x3101` from another post

Comment: The link provided by @Rinzwind is 404-ing right now, here's an alternative: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/host-controller-interface/

Comment: changed it Thanks

Comment: @Jeremy31 This command `hciconfig -a | awk '/[Vv]ersion/{print $3" "$4;exit}'` returns `4.0 (0x6)` but `btmgmt info | awk '/[Vv]ersion/{print $3" "$4;exit}'` shows `version 6` instead of `0x6`. How can the bluetooth version be inferred from the `btmgmt info` output ?

Comment: @SebMa https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-bluetooth-version-is-on-my-pc-f5d4cff7-c00d-337b-a642-d2d23b082793

Answer (score 7):

While not part of the original question, someone reading this may also wonder how to get the bluetooth version of a bluetooth peripheral (I know I did):

1. Pair the peripheral
2. Get its MAC address: `bluetoothctl devices`
3. Get its details: `hcitool info <mac address>`

Note that the ouput of the last command doesn't provide the HCI version, but the LMP version. Many other answers on the web to the original question points to the LMP version, not the HCI version. It can be decoded using the same equivalence table. In the answer above, both have the same value. I searched for an explanation of the difference between both, but didn't find it.

Comment: Very simplified, HCI is the interface/protocol between the adapter and the device/host. LMP is the perotocol on top that is used to manage bluetooth connections.

Comment: Even though the `hcitool` has been deprecated, I still haven't found any other tool to report the version of a connected Bluetooth device.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `inxi -E`.

It provides output in human readable form:

```
  Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Actions general adapter driver: btusb type: USB
  Report: btmgmt ID: hci1 state: up address: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX bt-v: 5.3
```

So in the example above the supported Bluetooth version is 5.3.

Excerpt from man:

> -E, --bluetooth
> Show bluetooth device data and report, if available. Shows
> state, address, IDs, version info.

https://smxi.org/docs/inxi-options.htm

Comment: My bluetooth dongle is 5.0 but above command shows `bt-v: 3.0`

Comment: @AlexJones: If you are certain that the displayed version is incorrect, you can open a new issue at https://codeberg.org/smxi/inxi/issues.